# Bash : uniq -v && uniq -i

Tags: bash, shell, uniq

I'm  using uniq -i to extract some terms from a file. But there is something wrong

I have 2 files for ex in the first one I have these 4 words

```
France
Construire 
TAO
construire
```

In the second file I have only these 2 words

```
Construire 
TAO
```

So I used this command

```
$ cat 1stfile.txt | grep -i 2ndfile.txt
```

And I have nothing as result. Can anyone explain to me why ?
And also I want to know how to make it search for a word even if it is  capitalize or not

I also tried the grep -v and what I have as result

```
Construire 
TAO
```

which is weird

Thank you

Comment: I think it's because grep is taking input from the second file instead of the stdin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep can work over standard input or file depending on arguments and options, Maybe what you want:

```
grep -f 2ndfile.txt -i 1stfile.txt
```

- `-f file` obtain PATTERN from FILE
- `-i` ignore case distinctions

man grep or grep --help for more details.

Comment: And If I have a lot of files like this